# ASPxMenu - Open submenu on click instead of hover (dx:ASPxMenu)

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, .net, devexpress

I am new to aspx menu. In my application I have used ASPxMenu. 
 By default submenu's are displayed on hover of parent element.
 I want the submenu to be opened only on click of parent element.
 How could I  achieve this ? Please help

```
<dx:ASPxMenu ID="" runat="server" AutoSeparators="RootOnly" AutoPostBack="true"
      ClientInstanceName="AdminMenu" SkinID="SubMenu" ItemAutoWidth="false" OnItemClick="AdminMenu_ItemClick"
                                        ItemStyle-Width="151px" SubMenuItemStyle-Width="174px" SubMenuItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
  <Items> 

<dx:MenuItem Text="Main menu" Target="~/main.aspx" Name="MainFunctions">
                                                <Items>
                                                    <dx:MenuItem Text="submenu 1" Name="submenu1" Target="~/submenu1.aspx"
                                                        Enabled="True">
                                                    </dx:MenuItem>
                                                    <dx:MenuItem Text="submenu 2" Name="submenu2" Target="~submenu12.aspx"
                                                        Enabled="True">
                                                    </dx:MenuItem>
                                                    <dx:MenuItem Text="submenu 3" Name="submenu3" Target="~/submenu13.aspx"
                                                        Enabled="True">
                                                    </dx:MenuItem>

                                                </Items>
                                            </dx:MenuItem>
  </Items>
                                    </dx:ASPxMenu>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either setting [`AppearAfter`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.ASPxMenuBase.AppearAfter.property) property to a large value from the markup or in `Page_Load` code-behind (measured in milliseconds):

```
<dx:ASPxMenu ID="Menu1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" AppearAfter="1000000" ...>
</dx:ASPxMenu>
```

And/or using client-side `ItemClick` event which calls `ShowSubMenu` function:

```
<dx:ASPxMenu ID="Menu1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ...>
    <ClientSideEvents ItemClick="function(s, e) { s.ShowSubMenu(e.item.indexPath); }" />
</dx:ASPxMenu>
```

Additionally, if you want to disable hovering, change the following `ASPxMenu.ItemStyle` and `ASPxMenu.ItemStyle.HoverStyle` to your own styling.

**Note:** If you want to process the event in server-side, it is necessary to set `e.processOnServer = true;`.

References:

- [Open menu sub items on click](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q238815/open-menu-sub-items-on-click)
- [Open subitems only when user clicks](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q275587/aspxmenu-open-subitems-only-when-user-clicks)
- [How to show Sub Items by clicking only](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q439187/aspxmenu-how-to-show-sub-items-by-clicking-only)
- [Stop displaying submenu on menu hover](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q521158/aspxmenu-stop-displaying-submenu-on-menu-hover)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It worked but the page reloads hence  submenu's are closed automatically. Here is the updated code                                            
 <ClientSideEvents ItemClick="function(s, e) {s.ShowSubMenu(e.item.indexPath);  e.processOnServer = true; }" /> can you provide me a solution ?